# Sonarqube can duplicate file has more than 1 on detail?

Tags: sonarqube

I am using sonarqube 6.7.

On Sonarqube, Measure, Duplication, there is Duplicated Files. If I click on Duplicated Files, detail will be displayed as seen on the picture.

I want to know can the number be more than 1 on each file? (as seen on picture, the number I have circled)

Thanks a lot

[duplicatedFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPHTA.png)